# TatSu: square brackets are being ignored in the grammar

Tags: python, parsing, tatsu

[TatSu](https://github.com/neogeny/TatSu) tends to ignore the square bracket characters, be it `[`, `]`, and the mix of two at times and recognize them at different times for some reason, which I will show in an example below I'm experimenting with in TatSu 5.10.1, Python 3.11.6, Linux 6.5.7 if it is related in any way.

I aim to render a subset of Markdown, but I'll start with a simplified grammar to discuss the issue.

(I'm using a unit separator as a rare character since other ways to disable whitespace handling were more confusing. If there's a more straightforward and reliable way to tell TatSu to recognize the whitespace as characters it should treat as a part of the text, that'll be useful to know, too.)

```
@@grammar::Markdown

@@whitespace :: /[␟]/

start = pieces $ ;

text = text:/[a-z]+/ ;

pieces = {text}*
    ;
```

This test code leads TatSu to ignore the `[]` and not fail with an error.
If I set the markdown_str as something else, like () or {}, TatSu will fail.
Individual square brackets, [ or ], won't lead to an exception.

```py
import tatsu

with open("./grammar.txt", "r") as grammar_file:
    grammar = grammar_file.read()

class MarkdownSemantics:

    def pieces(self, ast):
        return ''.join(ast)

parser = tatsu.compile(grammar)

markdown_str = "[]"
ast = parser.parse(markdown_str, semantics=MarkdownSemantics())
print(ast)
```

I expect this to be a bug, as I don't see what's so special about the square bracket characters. They are not defined as a part of whitespace to be ignored, and other characters similar to them are.

At the same time, I am told [here](https://github.com/neogeny/TatSu/issues/330#issuecomment-1826019908) that it's about learning parsing principles. Is my EBNF above allowing `[` or `]` to pass?

Comment: I'm sorry for not having taken a closer look at the issue you posted against TatSu. Something was indeed wrong.

Comment: TatSsu 10.4.0 has been released: https://pypi.org/project/TatSu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example code does not work, the semantics class definition expects the argument to `pieces()` to be a list of strings, but it is not.

Anyhow, the issue is with your `whitespace` definition. Contrary to what the documentation says, the `@@whitespace` directive in the grammar definition is interpreted as a list of characters to skip over between tokens (at least this is how I read the TatSu source code). Therefore, your grammar definition skips over `[` and `]`.

To disable white space handling, you can assign `None` or `False` to the `@@whitespace` directive:

```
@@whitespace :: None
```

Comment: The analysis is incorrect. ``@whitespace`` does indeed take a regular expression.

Comment: I've tested with TatSu 5.8.1 and the argument to `@whitespace` is not interpreted as a regular expression.

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, TatSu is incorrectly escaping regular expressions. A new release with a fix will be up ASAP.

Comment: TatSu 10.4.0 has been released: https://pypi.org/project/TatSu/

Comment: Please do an edit on your answer so I can remove the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `@@whitespace` definition (there's a weird character `␟`  there, but I don't think it's that).

The grammar works if you use this regexp instead:

```
@@whitespace :: /\s+/
```

It seems that TatSu is incorrectly escaping the original regex:

```
'[ ]'
re.compile('(?m)[\\[\\ \\]]+', re.MULTILINE)
```

Comment: I reopened the issue you had already posted.

Comment: Regarding the ␟ character, it was hard to make TatSu not ignore the whitespace, and documentation may be improved by using dnn's [idea above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77548586/703462).

Comment: I'll quote myself from GitHub regarding the character for clarity: "I'm using a unit separator as a rare character since other ways to disable whitespace handling were more confusing. If there's a more straightforward and reliable way to tell TatSu to recognize the whitespace as characters it should treat as a part of the text, that'll be useful to know, too."

Comment: The TatSu documentation is already updated. Yes, the correct way to _not_ skip over any whitespace is to use `@@whitespace :: None`. For historic, backwards-compatibility reasons TatSu defaults to `"(?m)\s+"` when no `@@whitespace` is specified. I thought about removing the default, but concluded that would break beginner grammars all around.